# Can 2 users on a single Windows PC share 1 OneDrive account with the same folder location?

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive, cloud-storage

On a Windows 10 PC, with a secondary partition,
there are two users linked to the same OneDrive Account. 
With both users’ OneDrive folders moved from `%USERPROFILE%` to the secondary partition (e.g., `D:\Onedrive`), can they share the same folder location so as not to duplicate files in storage?

Comment: Yes, but they cannot both link the MS account to their user profile

Comment: That's probably okay because the other user is the administrative account for that system and for backups wouldn't need to be used to modify the user data in any of the files, just the attributes. I suppose with the fall creators update the "Status" attribute could be a problem with backups.

Comment: Also, they can't both be logged in at the same time or it will result in an access violation and weird errors.